# throwing error in the RecyclerView adaptar, on creating the view holder

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use the RecyclerView inside the fragment. But as soon as i completed the code, contex in the adaptar is showing the error.

In the function `onCreateViewHolder()`, `context` is showing error :

> `from (android.content.Context) in layoutInflator cannot be applied to (com.practice.musicplayer.libraryfragment)`

```
public class SongCardAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SongCardAdapter.viewHolder> {

private ArrayList<SongCardModel> list;
private LibraryFragment context;

public SongCardAdapter(ArrayList<SongCardModel> list, LibraryFragment context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.libray_recycler_view_layout, parent, false);
    return new viewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
    SongCardModel model = list.get(position);
    holder.albumArt.setImageResource(model.getImage());
    holder.songName.setText(model.getSongName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //setting the size of the recyclerView to the size of the list
    return list.size();
}

public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView albumArt;
    TextView songName;
    public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        albumArt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_art);
        songName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
    }
}
}
```

For the Crash Logs

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.practice.musicplayer.LibraryFragment.onCreateView(LibraryFragment.java:27)`

and on the line 27 I have this code :

`libraryRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)libraryRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.library_recyclerview);`

Libraryfragment code :

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView libraryRecyclerView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    libraryRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) libraryRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.library_recyclerview);



    ArrayList<SongCardModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));

    SongCardAdapter adapter = new SongCardAdapter(list, getActivity());
    libraryRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_fragment, container, false);
}
}
```

SongCardModel :

```
public class SongCardModel {
//change the data type of image to string when accessing the online images
int image;
String songName;

//constructor of the class
public SongCardModel(int image, String songName) {
    this.image = image;
    this.songName = songName;
}

//getters and setter
public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getSongName() {
    return songName;
}

public void setSongName(String songName) {
    this.songName = songName;
}
}
```

Comment: method `from()` aspects a context but you're giving it a fragment, name it a context doesn't make it a context

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan i need more insights

Comment: `inflater.from(Context)` method wants to passed a context in its argument , but your fragment is not a context so it gives you error, it is like passing long to method expecting an int

Comment: from the logs it seems that it is the problem, then how to solve it

Comment: doesn't the answer from Hasan worked for you

Comment: no @AbhinavChauhan

Comment: why are you calling `findViewById` on the recyclerview, the `libraryRecyclerView` is null you cannot call a method on it , you need a non null view to call that method

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass your LibraryFragment inside the adapter, instead pass Context, then in your adapter initialization in your fragment, pass your activity. 
change your adapter constructor:

```
private ArrayList<SongCardModel> list;
private Context context;

public SongCardAdapter(ArrayList<SongCardModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

// adapter initialization in fragment
SongCardAdapter adapter = new SongCardAdapter(list, getActivity());
```

You can also not use context so in your onCreateViewHolder()

```
@NonNull
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.libray_recycler_view_layout, parent, false);
    return new viewHolder(view);
}
```

the error happened because, you're trying to bind your recyclerview with it self, which is currently null and this is incorrect way.
change your oncreateview like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_fragment, container, false);
    libraryRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.library_recyclerview);



    ArrayList<SongCardModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));
    list.add(new SongCardModel(R.drawable.roses_cover, "Roses"));

    SongCardAdapter adapter = new SongCardAdapter(list, getActivity());
    libraryRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look, i have edited the question and added the logs

Comment: in your oncreateview in your fragment, you have wrong implementation in binding your recyclerview, if you can post your fragment file especially in onCreateView(), I can take a look

Comment: yea sure!  posting the fragment file

Answer (score 1):

**You must call `parent.getContext()`**

**This:**

```
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.libray_recycler_view_layout, parent, false);
    return new viewHolder(view);
}
```

**Must be like this:**

```
@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.libray_recycler_view_layout, parent, false);
    return new viewHolder(view);
}
```

**In your fragment `onCreateView()`:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//view

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_fragment, container, false);

//find recyclerview

libraryRecyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.library_recyclerview);

//other stuff
.....
......

.......


//finally at the end 

return view;

}
```

Comment: Please take a look, i have edited the question and added the logs

Comment: Also keep what I told you before.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the line in your code which is

```
this.context = context;
```

with

```
this.context = context.getContext();
```

and see if it works.

Comment: nope, It didn't work. It removed the error but now app is crashing

Comment: Please take a look, i have edited the question and added the logs

Comment: So this is another problem, your first problem is solved. You can try other answers as they follow best practices guidance. To solve your crash issue replace line 27 with this code libraryRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.library_recyclerview); Here view is ur fragment inflated view.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the constructor of the viewholder, and create a separate the creation of it with the adding of stuff. The thing is that the View you are sending to the viewholder constructor is null-- so something's iffy.
here's an example.

```
public bind(View itemView) {
    albumArt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_art);
    songName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
}
```